# Sum arrays by index using functional programming

Tags: ruby, arrays, functional-programming

I have several equally sized arrays containing numbers (matrix), and I want to sum them all by their index (matrix columns).

For example, if I have:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

I want to get the result:

```
column_totals = [6, 8, 10, 12]
```

I understand how to do this imperatively, but how would I do this using functional programming? (Preferably, using built in Enumerable methods.) I wasn't very happy with any of the functional solutions I came up with.

I ended up using the Matrix class:

```
require 'matrix'

data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
matrix = Matrix[*data]
# Added sum method to Vector class.
matrix.column_vectors.map { |column| column.sum }
```

I'm happy enough with that solution, but am frustrated that I couldn't wrap my mind around a good functional solution without relying on the Matrix class.

Specifically, I was tripped up on the step to transform this:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

into this:

```
columns = [[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]]
```

Comment: From what I know of functional programming (not much), I would think the use of `Matrix` methods is spot-on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason to not use [`Array#transpose`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose)?

```
data.transpose
# => [[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]]
```

---

Alternatively, if you only want to use `Enumerable` methods to iterate, you can do

```
columns = data.inject(Array.new(data.first.length){[]}) { |matrix,row|
  row.each_with_index { |e,i| matrix[i] << e }
  matrix }
# => [[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]]
```

or

```
columns = data.flatten.group_by.with_index { |e,i| i % data[0].size }.values
# => [[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]]
```

To sum:

```
columns.map { |row| row.inject :+ }
# => [6, 8, 10, 12]
```

---

Thirdly, if you don't need the intermediate `columns`:

```
data.inject { |s,r| s.zip(r).map { |p| p.inject :+ } }
# => [6, 8, 10, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array#transpose`, as @Matt hinted, and then sum the arrays inside:

```
data.transpose.map {|a| a.reduce(:+) }
```